# PrimeFaces <p:media> tag taking some x seconds before rendering the pdf. How to show the status bar for the user

Tags: jsf, primefaces, media, statusbar

PrimeFaces `p:media` tag  is taking some x seconds before rendering a PDF. I would like to show the status bar for the user, but `p:media` does not have the `onstart` and `oncomplete` attributes to fire the status dialog. How can I achieve this?

```
<p:media value="#{bean.stream}" player="pdf">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{bean.id}" />
</p:media>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please put code into the question itself when possible, instead of an image.

Comment: Experts, Any solution to my need?

Comment: Hello BalusC, Please let me know if you have any solution for my requirement.